# hosting - which folder/file can I delete without causing problems?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I have a hosting account in bluehost and I've deleted the default wordpress installation in publich_html, but in the parent directory there is some files that I don't know their source or what they are for.
my question is which folder/file can I delete without causing any problem in my website ?
Image of folders : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GxWm.png
thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about which folders you would like to delete? Are they ones inside of public_html or ones like etc, mail, ssl, and tmp? Can you provide more information about what your goal of deleting them is and what is inside of them?

Comment: I just don't want random folders that I don't from where they came from or what they are for. I would like to delete all of them (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably do not even have filesystem permissions to delete these folders from your account. They are being used by your hosting provider to organize the contents of your account by keeping mail in one folder, server settings in another, FTP data in another, web site data in another, etc. You could contact your hosting provider to find out the exact use for each folder and whether you are able to remove it or not but my guess is you will not be able to remove them.

What you can do is clear out the contents of some of the folders. In particular the public_html folder and public_ftp folders are where everything available from your website and FTP site go. There shouldn't be any reason you can't eliminate everything from inside of these folders.